# Extracting Information from Java using ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr

I'm fairly new to ANTLR. I was wondering how to extract information from project files.

Using Java grammar, I need to extract the package names from a project, then the classes (including the package they come from), then the methods (including the packages and classes they come from) and finally the variables and their type (including the package, class, methods they come from).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the types, you need *full name and type resolution*.

That's not easy the face of scopes (consider accesses to members of anonymous classes!), generics, and type erasure rules, esp. with all the curlicues added by various versions of Java up thru version 8.  It is compounded by the fact that for real software, the tool has to read not only source files but class files to get type information.   You won't be able to extract the type information with just a parser.

People keep thinking if they have pure parser they're close to an interesting code analysis capability.  Parsing is the *easiest* part of program analysis. See [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).

If you want to get type information, find a tool that already computes it (e.g., the Eclipse Java AST package, the Java compiler, or some other tool designed specifically to support source code program analysis and transformation).